# 404 error when accessing non default app engine deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm getting a 404 error when trying to access an API in a non-default app engine deployment.

I have a deployed Cloud Endpoint (first version and not Cloud Framework) service with an app engine version of 1 and API version of 1. This is successfully deployed and accessible as the default version - http://{project-id}.appspot.com/_ah/api/{name}/**v1**/{relative-path}.

I also have a second deployment using Cloud Framework with an app engine version of 2 and API version of 2. I did this by first generating and deploying an API config file with the hostname {project-id}.appspot.com. I then deployed the new service under a version 2. Checking the AppEngine UI console shows the two different versions deployed with v1 as the default version serving all traffic.

The problem though is I cannot access an API on the 2nd version. When I try accessing an API method with the URL http://**2-dot-**{project-id}.appspot.com/_ah/api/{name}/**v2**/{relative-path}, I get a 404 error. I don't see any entries in the Log viewer for that request. However when I access the root path, http://**2-dot-**{project-id}.appspot.com, I also get a 404 but do see an entry in the Log viewer.

When I make v2 the default version by migrating all traffic to it, I can then access all APIs on the 2nd version via the URL http://{project-id}.appspot.com/_ah/api/{name}/**v2**/{relative-path}. I don't know why I can't access these APIs when it's the non-default version.

Am I accessing the v2 deployment the wrong way when it's the non-default version? I don't think so because when I make it the default the APIs work. Is it rather something to do with how I deployed the API spec for version 2? Does it for some reason not apply to a non-default 2-{project-id}.appspot.com request.

Comment: What happens if you visit `https://2-dot-{project-id}.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis`?

Comment: I get a Not Found message

Comment: If you don't mind providing more information over email, please file feedback on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/) at the top right and I'll contact you via email.